# Rule for eslint to ignore default packages

Tags: javascript, eslint

How to configure Eslint to get rid of this warning? `ws` is installed by default so I don't want it to be in my `package.json`. Or is it ok to have default packages specified in `package.json`?

[image]

Comment: I can't test right now but adding https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-node may help. Otherwise eslint has no way of knowing that a file is using node and has access to default modules.

Comment: Am I crazy or is `ws` **not** a built-in node package.  I thought for sure you had to install it from npm: [ws package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws).  I don't even see it listed in the node modules that node lists: [node GitHub](https://github.com/nodejs/node/tree/1c7b5db627a70b6ae1667a33a0a65ed5021c2dcf/lib).  Plainly, what makes you think that `ws` is a default package?

Comment: maybe in their environments ws is available by default I guess